# Google play Android crash - Native crash at /system/lib/libcutils.so

Tags: android, crash, google-play, native, android-4.4-kitkat

I am getting crash reports from Google Play. And all those error occur only on Android v4.4.2.

I don't known what is causing the crash and how do i fix it.

Hope someone can help me.

Log:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/ja3gxx/ja3g:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9500XXUFNI2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'
pid: 28579, tid: 28587, name: FinalizerDaemon >>> com.iam.nearer.app <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'heap corruption detected by dlfree'
r0 00000000 r1 00006fab r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 00000000 r6 00006fab r7 0000010c
r8 00000000 r9 72822f48 sl 7282c108 fp 72a90b24
ip 00000016 sp 72a909b8 lr 401090e1 pc 401182d0 cpsr 000f0010
d0 65746564206e6f64 d1 207962206465746c
d2 6dba675800000066 d3 0000010000000072
d4 8000000000000000 d5 0000000000000000
d6 4b83075000000000 d7 42c8000000000003
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000
d18 0000000000000000 d19 8000000000000000
d20 0000000000004000 d21 0000000000000000
d22 0000000000004000 d23 8000000000000000
d24 0000000000000000 d25 4008000000000000
d26 3fc2f112df3e5244 d27 0000000000000001
d28 00000000000000e6 d29 00000000000000e5
d30 0000000000000001 d31 0000000000004000
scr 80000010

backtrace:
#00 pc 000222d0 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 000130dd /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02 pc 000132f1 /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00012027 /system/lib/libc.so
#04 pc 00021b84 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00012b0d /system/lib/libc.so
#06 pc 0000f22d /system/lib/libc.so
#07 pc 000117ef /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1222)
#08 pc 0000dd1f /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
#09 pc 000af60b /system/lib/libskia.so (SkMallocPixelRef::~SkMallocPixelRef()+10)
#10 pc 0008e1b1 /system/lib/libskia.so
#11 pc 0008e211 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPixelRef::globalUnref()+20)
#12 pc 000915cf /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::freePixels()+36)
#13 pc 000915fb /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::setPixelRef(SkPixelRef*, unsigned int)+26)
#14 pc 0009168f /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::setPixels(void*, SkColorTable*)+16)
#15 pc 000bfe93 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPixelRef::unlockPixels()+32)
#16 pc 000915c9 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::freePixels()+30)
#17 pc 000917af /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::~SkBitmap()+4)
#18 pc 0002a5db /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::ResourceCache::destructorLocked(SkBitmap*)+50)
#19 pc 0002a613 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::ResourceCache::destructor(SkBitmap*)+20)
#20 pc 0001e84c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#21 pc 0004f28b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#22 pc 00027c60 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#23 pc 0002ec9c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#24 pc 0002c300 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#25 pc 000618f1 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#26 pc 00061915 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#27 pc 00056603 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#28 pc 0000d280 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#29 pc 0000d418 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
401182b0 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
401182c0 ea006fce e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000 
401182d0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
401182e0 ea006fc6 e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000 
401182f0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40118300 ea006fbe e1520003 8a000102 f5d1f040 
40118310 e92d4001 e3520010 3a00003f e3520d0d 
40118320 aa00004c e2603000 e213300f 0a00000e 
40118330 e0422003 e1b0cf83 44d1e001 44c0e001 
40118340 24d1c001 24d1e001 24c0c001 24c0e001 
40118350 e1b0ce83 aa000001 f4a1030d f480031d 
40118360 3a000001 f421070d f400071d e2522080 
40118370 3a000014 f4210acd f4000acd f4210acd 
40118380 f4000acd f4210acd f4000acd f4210acd 
40118390 f4000acd f4210acd f4000acd f4210acd 
401183a0 f4000acd f4210acd f4000acd f4210acd 

code around lr:
401090c0 447b4b13 42b3e010 4812d10e 44786a1e 
401090d0 ec90f7fb ea42f00d 46224631 e8f2f00f 
401090e0 d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb 
401090f0 44782403 ec7ef7fb f001e002 6804fa87 
40109100 fa84f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003c2e2 
40109110 0003c2d6 0003c2ce 0003c2aa bf7ef7ff 
40109120 4a3e4b3d 43f0e92d 4606b08b 447b460d 
40109130 6823589c 930946a1 fa68f001 8000f8d0 
40109140 d0482d00 f0104628 280ff8af d8444604 
40109150 ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e90cf00d 
40109160 d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debc2 
40109170 e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478 
40109180 4a2aec3a 46332120 447aa801 fdd4f013 
40109190 a8012101 f8d6f01b 46061c42 e011d104 
401091a0 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622 
401091b0 1c43e948 d11e4607 fa28f001 29046801
```

Similar errors have occurred for other apps, which are caused by Android OS bugs.

Comment: May I please know, why was the question downvoted?

Comment: Are you developing with Android NDK?

Comment: @ArfanMirza no, SDK.

Answer (score -2):

Remove your bitmap.recycle() calls and set all your bitmaps = null when your done using them. Let the GC clear the bitmaps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It is the answer, looks like is crashing clearing the bitmaps from the heap:
Abort message: 'heap corruption detected by dlfree'

#19 pc 0002a613 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::ResourceCache::destructor(SkBitmap*)+20)

Comment: @Rod.Jav That isn't the answer. Th culprit was the Facebook Fresco library, and an update resolved the issue.